node.js exectuale capabilites are not inherited to native addon
I try to debug a problem with the npm module "raw-socket".
For that i wrote a c++ addon that prints the capabilities of the running executable. (in this case node):
addon.cc
#include <napi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/capability.h>

void print_capabilities(const char *process_name) {
    cap_t caps;
    char *caps_text;

    caps = cap_get_proc();
    if (caps == NULL) {
        perror("cap_get_proc");
        return;
    }

    caps_text = cap_to_text(caps, NULL);
    if (caps_text == NULL) {
        perror("cap_to_text");
        cap_free(caps);
        return;
    }

    printf("%s capabilities: %s\n", process_name, caps_text);

    // Freigeben des Speichers
    cap_free(caps_text);
    cap_free(caps);
}

Napi::Value ForkAndPrintCapabilities(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info) {
    Napi::Env env = info.Env();

    printf("Hallo from main\n");
    print_capabilities("Main");

    return Napi::String::New(env, "Fork and capabilities printed.");
}

Napi::Object Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {
    exports.Set(Napi::String::New(env, "forkAndPrintCapabilities"), Napi::Function::New(env, ForkAndPrintCapabilities));
    return exports;
}

NODE_API_MODULE(addon, Init)

index.js
const addon = require('./build/Release/addon');

console.log("Exectuable:", process.execPath);
addon.forkAndPrintCapabilities();

binding.gyp
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "addon",
      "sources": ["addon.cc"],
      "include_dirs": [
        "<!(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include\")",
        "node_modules/node-addon-api",                                                       
        "/usr/include/node",                                                                 
        "usr/local/include/node",  
      ],
      "dependencies": [
        "<!(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').gyp\")"
      ],
      "cflags_cc": ["-fexceptions"],
      "libraries": ["-lcap"]
    }
  ]
}

The addon is build an the code executed as expected.
But it does not print what i was expecting.
My node.js exectubel /usr/bin/node has this capabilites:
cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw=eip. But the c++ addon prints: =ep
Full output of executing:
marc@workstation:~/projects/playground/node-addon$ node index.js
Exectuable: /home/marc/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.0/bin/node
Hallo from main
Main capabilities: =
marc@workstation:~/projects/playground/node-addon$ sudo node index.js
[sudo] Passwort für marc: 
Exectuable: /usr/bin/node
Hallo from main
Main capabilities: =ep
marc@workstation:~/projects/playground/node-addon$ getcap /usr/bin/node
/usr/bin/node cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw=eip
marc@workstation:~/projects/playground/node-addon

Can some one explain to my why the node addon has not the capabilities as the node execrable /usr/bin/node? Is this due to node.js "isolation/vm" stuff?
Thanks in advance.
